# Assing multiple enum values to one class property

Tags: java, enums

I have one java class like below:

```
public class Location 
{
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public String country;
    public enum type{Beach,Forest,Hills,Desert};
}
```

as above `type` member is enum type and i want to assign **multiple enum values** to type proprties like one `Location` object has more then one type properties like it has `Hills` as well as `Forest`.

then how should i have to do it?
where to declare enum and how to assign to enum values to one object.

Is it possible to assign to enum values one object without using array?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `Collection` to store a variable number of values. Since you don't want to have duplicates use a `Set`. For enums exist `java.util.EnumSet` which has a compact and efficient way to store multiple values:

```
public class Location 
{
    public enum Type {Beach,Forest,Hills,Desert};
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public String country;
    public EnumSet<Type> types = EnumSet.noneOf(Type.class); // start with empty set
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store them in class variables:

```
private final Terrain first = Terrain.BEACH;
private final Terrain second = Terrain.DESERT;
```

Similarly, you can store them in a collection of terrains if that is more appropriate:

```
private final Set<Terrain> terrains = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Terrain.BEACH, Terrain.DESERT));
```

Or use an EnumSet:

```
private final EnumSet<Terrain> terrains = EnumSet.of(Terrain.BEACH, Terrain.DESERT);
```

On a side note, it is more conventional to declare enumerations in their own file, I have assumed that it will be called `Terrain`. Also, constants (thus also enum values) are usually written in capital letters.

Comment: it is not feasible for me because it some location has more then two type then what happen?

Comment: What if there is a 3rd or 4th type?

Comment: OP indicated that he did not want an array, which I interpreted as not wanting any kind of collection. Thats why I only included it as a remark.